# ListView not displaying correctly on iOS

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am coding Xamarin forms app that displays users comments in a ListView.

The problem is it displays correctly on Android but on iOS it is all out of the box (As shown in the screenshots)

The items are added after an async web request is run gathering the information, I don't know if that affects it.

**Android Screen**

[image]

**iOS Screen**

[image]

My XAML

```xml
<local:PostListView x:Name="MessageView" HasUnevenRows="True" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" Refreshing="MessageView_Refreshing" SeparatorVisibility="None" BackgroundColor="#7ed6df">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:PostViewCell>
                <StackLayout x:Name="MessageLayout" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Padding="10, 10, 15, 10">
                    <Image Source="options_icon.png" HeightRequest="18" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="5, 0, 5, 0" IsVisible="{Binding ShowBanners}">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OptionClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Body}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{Binding BodyColor}" FontSize="15" Margin="0, 10, 0, 10"/>
                    <StackLayout x:Name="MessageFooter" Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding ShowBanners}">
                        <Image x:Name="LikeSource" Source="{Binding LikeImageSource}" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0, 0, 10, 0">
                            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding LikeClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Image>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Timestamp}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </local:PostViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</local:PostListView>
```

PostViewCell.cs

```cs
using SocialNetwork.iOS.Renderers;
using SocialNetwork.Renderers;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PostViewCell), typeof(PostViewCelliOS))]
namespace SocialNetwork.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class PostViewCelliOS : ViewCellRenderer
    {

        public override UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            cell.SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "All messed up" is not a useful description of the problem.

Comment: @Jason Edited and added detail.

Comment: Add a different background colour to each StackLayout so you can know which one is problematic.  Also, try using a Grid instead of stacking stack layouts.

Comment: @RodrigoE. I don't think a grid will fix it and when setting the background color I can see it goes out of the layout

Comment: Can you post the code of your `PostViewCell`?

Comment: @RogerLeblanc Edited into the post :)

Comment: Maybe remove padding/margin and look if it looks better? Remove one by one and see if it changes anything. As maybe height of cell is calculated without it. Or disable renderer. Does it change anything?

Comment: remove Margin="0, 0, 10, 0" from image and put it parent stack layout. Or better to use Grid for that and remove all padding and margin

Comment: @ZiyadGodil I tried removing the image margin but it didn't change anything, And I'm not experienced enough with grid to be able to build it, I've always worked with StackLayouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create a StackLayout wrapping your content like:

```
<local:PostViewCell>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="MessageLayout" BackgroundColor="White" Margin="10, 10, 10, 10" Padding="10, 10, 15, 10">
            <Image Source="options_icon.png" HeightRequest="18" HorizontalOptions="End" Margin="5, 0, 5, 0" IsVisible="{Binding ShowBanners}">
                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OptionClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
            </Image>
            <Label Text="{Binding Body}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="{Binding BodyColor}" FontSize="15" Margin="0, 10, 0, 10"/>
            <StackLayout x:Name="MessageFooter" Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding ShowBanners}">
                <Image x:Name="LikeSource" Source="{Binding LikeImageSource}" HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Margin="0, 0, 10, 0">
                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding LikeClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                </Image>
                <Label Text="{Binding Timestamp}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</local:PostViewCell>
```